# Assigning HTML Link to Tree Node Text

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, data-visualization

Can't seem to assign HTML link to Text, on Nodes of a D3 Tree...

Full code available at: http://bl.ocks.org/Guerino1/raw/ed80661daf8e5fa89b85/

I use the following code (at about line 162):

```
      nodeEnter.append("svg:a")
          .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.hlink; })
        .append("text")
          .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
          .attr("dy", "-10")
          .attr("fill", "Blue")
          .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
          .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
          .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
```

The code seems to work fine with Force Directed Graphs but I can't get it to work with this tree.  When I open up the DOM Tree, I find that the HTML link is not being assigned even though the DOM elements "a" and "text" exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are removing the `href` property from your data. Have a look at `nodes` when passe to the `update` function and then have a look at it when passed to the `.data` function.

This line is the culprit: `var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse();`

Edit:

Correction: the `nodeByName` function is the culprit.

Do this:

```
function nodeByName(name) {

    for (var i = 0; i < nodeSet.length; i++){
        if(nodeSet[i].name === name) return nodeSet[i];
    }

    console.log("ERROR: This node name is not in the node set.")

    return nodeSet[name] = {name: name};

    //return nodeSet[name] || (nodeSet[name] = {name: name});
}
```

Comment: I see it.  The API states that the tree.nodes() method traverses the tree and sets certain attributes for each node.  It seems to improperly "strip" all other data.  The follow-up questions now become... 1) Why is the tree.nodes() method stripping all other data from the node set? And, 2) What's the best way to prevent this or fix it?  Thx.

Comment: Looks like you are actually replacing `nodes`. The `root` parameter passed to `nodes()` does not contain the `href` data.

Comment: Correction, it was `nodeByName` function. See new answer. It is all working.